# How to fetch data from multidimensional array object in wordpress (php)

Tags: php

I need to fetch the value of data "Studie". Below data is fetched through a custom table by wordpress query . How can i do it ?

```
Array ( [0] => 
stdClass Object ( [data] => a:8:{i:14;O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:5:"label";s:7:"Fornavn";s:5:"value";s:4:"test";s:4:"type";s:5:"Fname";s:4:"meta";N;}
i:15;O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:5:"label";s:9:"Etternavn";s:5:"value";s:3:"net";s:4:"type";s:5:"Lname";s:4:"meta";N;}
i:16;O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:5:"label";s:6:"Kjønn";s:5:"value";s:6:"Kvinne";s:4:"type";s:5:"Radio";s:4:"meta";N;}
i:17;O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:5:"label";s:6:"Studie";s:5:"value";s:8:"Juss UiB";s:4:"type";s:6:"Select";s:4:"meta";N;}
i:18;O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:5:"label";s:3:"År";s:5:"value";s:6:"1. År";s:4:"type";s:6:"Select";s:4:"meta";N;}
i:13;O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:5:"label";s:6:"E-post";s:5:"value";s:14:"test@test2.com";s:4:"type";s:5:"Email";s:4:"meta";N;}
i:20;O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:5:"label";s:7:"Adresse";s:5:"value";s:11:"h jhgjklhjk";s:4:"type";s:7:"Textbox";s:4:"meta";N;}
i:21;O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:5:"label";s:2:"By";s:5:"value";s:3:"jhj";s:4:"type";s:7:"Textbox";s:4:"meta";N;}} ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching data from wordpress table. To understand better, It need to be unserialize first

> OBJECT - result will be output as a numerically indexed array of row
>   objects.
>
> OBJECT_K - result will be output as an associative array of row
>   objects, using first column's values as keys (duplicates will be
>   discarded).
>
> ARRAY_A - result will be output as an numerically indexed array of
>   associative arrays, using column names as keys.
>
> ARRAY_N - result will be output as a numerically indexed array of
>   numerically indexed arrays.

Form : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results#SELECT_Generic_Results

If your $user be the variable that stored result from wordpress query.

```
$mydata = unserialize($user[0]->data); 
print_r( $mydata);
```

Value of `i` be the Id of each `stdClass Object`, Your required variable `Studie` is at `i:17` [I wrote this line on the basis of your Array in question.]

Try this

```
echo $mydata[17]->value;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$array_json_data = json_decode($array_value)
```

Comment: I want to fetch value of "studie ". i tried json decode but it's not much useful.